# Why are my jalapeño peppers turning black?

Tags: diagnosis, raised-beds, peppers

I have a healthy jalapeño pepper plant but noticed that the peppers have a black patch on them. What could be the reason for that?

[image] 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like high light/low moisture, although I could be wrong Do you irrigate?

Comment: Yes I irrigate. Do you have some references I can read up?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to sun exposure and totally harmless! They'll stay green if they're shaded by a leaf.